# BIOMETRIC DISABLE

Tags: java, android, android-biometrico

Tengo un error al  correr mi api con un cel sin biométrica o con biométrica desactivada, solo funciona si esta activada la biometría y no encuentro porque se me rompe

Clase `biometric`, mando false en `BIOMETRIC_ERROR_NONE_ENROLLED` al método de la master `saveBiometricEnabled(false)` pero no me lo toma :

```
   private void checkBiometric() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, NoSuchProviderException, NoSuchPaddingException {

        BiometricManager biometricManager = BiometricManager.from(context);
        String error;

        switch (biometricManager.canAuthenticate()) {
            case BiometricManager.BIOMETRIC_SUCCESS:
                showBiometricDialog();

                break;
            case BiometricManager.BIOMETRIC_ERROR_NO_HARDWARE:
                saveBiometricDisplayConfig(false);
            case BiometricManager.BIOMETRIC_ERROR_HW_UNAVAILABLE:
                saveBiometricDisplayConfig(false);
            case BiometricManager.BIOMETRIC_ERROR_NONE_ENROLLED:
                saveBiometricEnabled(false);
                listener.iniciarSesion();
                break;
        }
    }
```

clase master :

```
protected void saveBiometricEnabled(boolean isEnabled) {
    Context c = MasterController.this;

    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getBaseContext().getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.preference_file_key), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    sharedPref.getBoolean("isBiometricEnabled", false);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("isBiometricEnabled", isEnabled);
    editor.apply();
}

protected void saveBiometricDisplayConfig(boolean shouldShow) {
    Context c = MasterController.this;

    SharedPreferences sharedPref = c.getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.preference_file_key), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("shouldShowBiometricCheck", shouldShow);

    editor.apply();

}

// trae info del cel si esta activado o no el inicio biometrico
protected boolean obtenerBiometricEnabled() {
    SharedPreferences sp = MasterController.this.getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.preference_file_key), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    return sp.getBoolean("isBiometricEnabled", true);
}

protected boolean obtenerDisplayBiometrics() {
    SharedPreferences sp = MasterController.this.getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.preference_file_key), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    return sp.getBoolean("shouldShowBiometricCheck", true);
}
```

Clase login :

```
   @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.continuar:
                if (esPrimerLogin && shouldShowUserField) {

                    iniciarSesion();
//                            CustomDialog customDialog = new CustomDialog(InicioSesionControlador.this,
//                                    InicioSesionControlador.this);
//                            customDialog.show();
                }
//                  else if(obtenerBiometricEnabled() && obtenerDisplayBiometrics()){
//                        try {
//                            firstLoginBiometricAssociation();
//                        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
//                            e.printStackTrace();
//                        } catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
//                            e.printStackTrace();
//                        } catch (NoSuchProviderException e) {
//                            e.printStackTrace();
//                        } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
//                            e.printStackTrace();
//                        } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
//                            e.printStackTrace();
//                        }
//                    }
                else {
                    iniciarSesion();
                }


                break;
            case R.id.nuevaCuenta:
                goToRegistroStep1();
                break;
            case R.id.txtCambiarUsuario:
                txtUserLogeado.setText("");
                mostrarCamposPrimerLogin(true);
                deviceID = obtenerSharedPreferencesValue("").equals("") ? UUID.randomUUID().toString() : obtenerSharedPreferencesValue(getString(R.string.uid));
                guardarSharedPreferencesValue(getString(R.string.uid), deviceID);
                esPrimerLogin = true;
                shouldShowUserField = true;
                break;
            case R.id.recuperarpassword:
                goToRecuperarPassword(shouldShowUserField);
                break;

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        //esPrimerLogin();
        moveTaskToBack(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        //esPrimerLogin();
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        esPrimerLogin();
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void closeBiometricModal() {
        saveBiometricDisplayConfig(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void iniciarSesion() {
        if (esPrimerLogin) {
            deviceID = obtenerSharedPreferencesValue("").equals("") ? UUID.randomUUID().toString() : obtenerSharedPreferencesValue(getString(R.string.uid));
            guardarSharedPreferencesValue(getString(R.string.uid), deviceID);
            try {
                if (validarCamposForm(txtUsuario, txtContrasena)) {

                    login(TipoTransaccionEnum.LOGIN, txtUsuario.getText().toString(), txtContrasena.getText().toString(), deviceID, esPrimerLogin, null, InicioSesionControlador.this, true);

                }
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        if (!obtenerDisplayBiometrics() && !esPrimerLogin) { //obtenerDisplayBiometrics() &&
            try {
                if (validarContrasenia(txtContrasena)) {
                    login(TipoTransaccionEnum.LOGIN, obtenerSharedPreferencesValue(getString(R.string.keyusr)), txtContrasena.getText().toString(), deviceID, esPrimerLogin, null, InicioSesionControlador.this, true);
                }


            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if (obtenerDisplayBiometrics() && !esPrimerLogin) { //!obtenerDisplayBiometrics() &&
            try {
                login(TipoTransaccionEnum.LOGIN, obtenerSharedPreferencesValue(getString(R.string.keyusr)), obtenerSharedPreferencesValue(getString(R.string.keypwd)), deviceID, esPrimerLogin, null, InicioSesionControlador.this, true);
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

    public void firstLoginBiometricAssociation() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, NoSuchProviderException, InvalidKeyException, NoSuchPaddingException {
//if(esPrimerLogin){
        new BiometricCheck(this, this);
        // }
    }


    public void mostrarBiometric() {

        if (obtenerBiometricEnabled() && obtenerDisplayBiometrics()) {
            try {
                firstLoginBiometricAssociation();
            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (NoSuchProviderException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

El error que me sale :

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
> method 'android.content.res.Resources
> android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference
>
> dodne se rome:  at
> mobilewalletbilletera.twoinnovateit.com.bancoguayaquil.ViewController.Genericos.MasterController.saveBiometricEnabled(MasterController.java:451)

Comment: En esta función `saveBiometricEnabled` solo obtienes los valores del `SharedPreferences`, ejecutaste en modo debug y es en esa función donde deja de funcionar?

Comment: deja de funcionar cuando llega a : 
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getBaseContext().getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.preference_file_key), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

Comment: me salta este error en el log :      Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference

Comment: como que el resource del context llega null pero nose como arreglarlo

Comment: En esta función `obtenerBiometricEnabled()` no utilizas esa variable. Funciona esa función? Si es así entonces utiliza esa misma línea para la función que te da error.

Answer (score 0):

El valor del contexto es null, usa como contexto  `MasterController.this` :

```
protected void saveBiometricEnabled(boolean isEnabled) {
    Context c = MasterController.this;

    //SharedPreferences sharedPref = getBaseContext().getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.preference_file_key), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    SharedPreferences sharedPref = c.getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.preference_file_key), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    sharedPref.getBoolean("isBiometricEnabled", false);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("isBiometricEnabled", isEnabled);
    editor.apply();
}
```